# Scroll function works fast in mac and touchpad

Tags: javascript, html, macos, carousel, swiper.js

I have a slider and I made a code that goes next and prev with mouse scroll. But it doesn't work well with mac and touchpad. how can I fix it? Can I put some delay or something I tried to use some setTimeout but it didn't work well or I didn't do it right.

```
$('#body').on('mousewheel', function (event) {
  if (typeof event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY === 'undefined') {
    console.log("could not find mouse deltas")
  }
  var deltaY = event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY;
  var scrolledUp = deltaY < 0;
  var scrolledDown = deltaY > 0;
  if (scrolledDown) {
    if (swiper_color.activeIndex > 2) {
      goTop();
      activeIndexToTwo();
    } else {
        swiper_color.slidePrev();
        swiper_image.slidePrev();
        swiper_desc.slidePrev();
        swiper_title.slidePrev();
        swiper_jar.slidePrev();
    }
  }
  if (scrolledUp) {
    if (swiper_color.activeIndex < 2) {
      swiper_color.slideNext();
      swiper_image.slideNext();
      swiper_desc.slideNext();
      swiper_title.slideNext();
      swiper_jar.slideNext();
    } else {
      checkscroll();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend throttling the function. You could write a throttle function, or use one from a library like Lodash ([Lodash throttle docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle))

```
function yourFn (event) {
  // ... all of your js here
  // ...
}

$('#body').on('mousewheel', _.throttle(yourFn, 100));
```

The 100(ms) above means your function can only fire every 100ms, feel free to modify the time to your liking.

Comment: I tried that but it stacks the function i scroll once then it works 3 times with 100 ms between